# Problems in run tornado Demos of "blog"

Tags: python, mysql, blogs, tornado

When I try to Run the 'blog' demo in the tornado package. I got problems as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./blog.py", line 196, in <module>
    main()
  File "./blog.py", line 190, in main
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
  File "./blog.py", line 63, in __init__
    user=options.mysql_user, password=options.mysql_password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/database.py", line 58, in __init__
    args = dict(conv=CONVERSIONS, use_unicode=True, charset="utf8",
NameError: global name 'CONVERSIONS' is not defined
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have solve the problem by install mysqldb.

Answer (score 0):

first you should install python-MySQLdb,then read README in the blog demo